# Convex Decomposition with IRIS-NP

Tags: drake

I am trying to use IRIS (more precisely, IRIS-NP) for the convex decomposition of the subspace defined by `g(x) ≤ 0` within a specific domain.  Here, `x` is not exactly a configuration space and not related to any plant.  Hence it seems more natural to use `Iris` instead of `IrisInConfigurationSpace`.

I see that `IrisOptions` supports `prog_with_additional_constraints`.  However, it doesn't seem to be used in `Iris`, only `IrisInConfigurationSpace`.

Is there a way to pass additional constraints to `Iris`?  Or to use IRIS-NP without an associated plant/context?  Or would it be easier for me to create a dummy plant with the same DoF as dimensions of `x`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the sentiment... IRIS/IRIS-NP is really more general than kinematic problems (although it works hard to make the collision computations efficient).

The primary distinction between IRIS and IRIS-NP, of course, is that IRIS assumes that the "obstacles" are convex.  Presumably you don't have that for your `g(x) \le 0`. So I suspect IRIS-NP is what you want.

Given the current API, I do think that making a dummy plant with a configuration space of the right dimension, with joint limits to define the boundaries of your search space, and no collision geometry is probably the right way to give it a try. If it proves useful, we can look at making the API more ergonomic for this use case in the future.

BTW -- Now that more people are trying IRIS-NP, I'm starting to optimize it's performance. Expect it to get faster in the coming month.